# link to the card in html

Tags: html, css, tags, href

I need to put a link `href="/favourites_new/"` in the text so that when I click on the card (not on the text itself) I could go to another page. There is my simple code

```
<div class="left-card-parent">
    <div class="left-card">
        <h1 class="left-card-h2"> &#11013;</h1>
            <p>selected</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: Make your card `<a>` tag instead of <div>. And put that href to that card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all you code inside an   tag
for example

```html
<a href=your link here>
<div class="left-card-parent">
    <div class="left-card">
        <h1 class="left-card-h2"> &#11013;</h1>
            <p>selected</p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```